# Keras how is the input layer defined (basic understanding) number of layers

Tags: keras, input, layer

I try to follow a tutorial.

The building of the model starts with

```
netw <- keras_model_sequential()

### one input layer, one output layer and one hidden layer
netw %>% layer_dense(units = 500, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(6)) %>%
  layer_dense(units=300, activation="relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units=2, activation="softmax")
```

units define the number of nodes. I am confused about the number of layers. The input layer should have 6 nodes, since there are 6 features. Why does it have units=500? Does this really specify an input layer with 6 nodes and a second layer with 500 nodes? So there would be 4 layers instead of the three stated in the comment?

Comment: Number of nodes has not to be the same as input features. Most of the time, number of nodes in the first layer are more than input features. Apart from that, by convention, we don't count input layer when we are talking about number of layers because it is trivial that every network has an input layer. So, this network has 3 layers. - "4 layers in fact, because it has an input layer too"

Answer (score 0):

The input shape does refer to the size of the input layer. This is the number of data point being fed into the network while `units = 500` is the number of network nodes the data is being passed to.

Here is a visualization of your model:

[image: Model visualisation]

As you can see, there are indeed four layers in the model. The input layer is not generally counted because every network will generally contain an input layer. More specifically, the input layer is not a computation layer, so there are only three levels of computation being carried out.